# Does the formation of a firm imply the creation of organisational capital?

Tags: industrial-organisation, theory-of-the-firm

According to Ronald Coase ([The Nature of the Firm](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1111/j.1468-0335.1937.tb00002.x), 1937) firms are created because this reduces transaction costs compared to market transactions. Transactions are internalised because of the complexity involved in specifying them in contracts. It would seem that internalising a transaction involves internal processes and capacities which will likely be specific to the firm to some degree. Would these be considered a form of organisational capital?